# Change value of a empty textview after a activity starts android

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I have a simple app which has two activities, and which runs as follows:

#### Activity 1:

```
public void SendMessage(View view){
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,DisplayMessage.class);
    EditText editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message=editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

#### Activity 2:

The "Extra_Message" will displayed at a single `TextView` and increased by 1 and repeated 10 times each result of the addition will be displayed on the `TextView` with 1000ms of delay.

```
Intent intent= getIntent();
String message=intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
int no= Integer.parseInt(message);
TextView textView=new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(40);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    message=Integer.toString(no);
    textView.setText(message);
    setContentView(textView);
    no++;

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that I don't know where should I run this code. It should run after the creation of the second activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling Thread.sleep() on the main (or UI) thread is a bad idea. In fact, ANYTHING stopping the main thread is a bad idea. One solution: create a Handler in your second Activity and post delayed Runnable to it. Use `handler.postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)` to schedule the runnable on the thread associated with the Handler (in this case the main thread).

```
private Handler handler;
private TextView textView;
private Runnable updateTextRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        String message = ...
        textView.setText(message);
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

public void onCreate(Bundle saved) {
    super.onCreate(saved);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id);
    handler = new Handler();
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    handler.postDelayed(updateTextRunnable, 1000);
}
```

You can stop it by calling `handler.removeCallbacks(updateTextRunnable);` -- I'll leave it you to decide where to stop running it.

Answer (score 1):

Just run it in onCreate() method of the second activity.

Comment: When I run it onCreate Method the code runs but the problem is that you cant see the addition steps only the result appears after the onCreate is executed. I need to see the text view changes exp: user input is 10. Then second activity should show periodically 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 at the textview with 1000ms delays.Thanks for answering

Comment: Because you are overwriting message in every iteration with the no ans then set it to the textView. Instead use StringBuffer and append method. Something like this: StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
   textView.setText(sb.append(no).toString());

Answer (score 0):

You could make an object of thread class, and put inside it the code for the buckle.

Then each "for" iteration, call

```
thread.sleep(500);
```

This way, the system will wait `0.5 sec` in each iteration